# How I can insert data in a String from registerReceiver (Service) ? Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcast

How I can `insert data` in a `String` from `registerReceiver`, I have below codes .

In my `Service` I writed this code :

```
        Intent ir=new Intent(); 
        ir.setAction(MY_ACTION);
        ir.putExtra("Webresponse", Webresponse); 
        sendBroadcast(ir);
```

And in `Activity` I get data :

```
private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
          String datapassed = arg1.getStringExtra("Webresponse");
          Toast.makeText(ChatPage.this,
                "Triggered by Service!\n"
                + "Data passed: " + datapassed,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
    }
```

Then  in `onCreate` I can get data and see data with `Toast` but I need that `insert data` in a String value:

```
MyReceiver m = new  MyReceiver();
                            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                            intentFilter.addAction(ChatPage_Service.MY_ACTION);
                            registerReceiver(m, intentFilter);
```

I need to :

```
String values = registerReceiver(m, intentFilter);
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you mean you need the value of `datapassed` in your Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fill a ListView you should fill it in your `private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver` .

For example this is my code :

```
private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
          datapassed = arg1.getStringExtra("Webresponse");
            try {
                XmlToDocument xmltodoc = new XmlToDocument();
                Document doc = xmltodoc.getDomElement(datapassed);
                // normalize text representation
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                NodeList listOfPersons = doc
                        .getElementsByTagName("user");

                adapter.clear();
                for (int s = 0; s < listOfPersons.getLength(); s++) {
                    StructPasokhgoo stp = new StructPasokhgoo();
                    Node firstPersonNode = listOfPersons.item(s);
                    if (firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                        Element firstPersonElement = (Element) firstPersonNode;
                        NodeList ageList = firstPersonElement
                                .getElementsByTagName("group");
                        Element ageElement = (Element) ageList
                                .item(0);

                        NodeList textAgeList = ageElement
                                .getChildNodes();
                        group = ((Node) textAgeList.item(0))
                                .getNodeValue().trim();
                        if (group.equals("admin")) {
                            //----//
                            NodeList firstNameList = firstPersonElement
                                    .getElementsByTagName("id");
                            Element firstNameElement = (Element) firstNameList
                                    .item(0);

                            NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement
                                    .getChildNodes();
                            id = ((Node) textFNList.item(0))
                                    .getNodeValue().trim();
                            //----//
                            NodeList lastNameList = firstPersonElement
                                    .getElementsByTagName("name");
                            Element lastNameElement = (Element) lastNameList
                                    .item(0);

                            NodeList textLNList = lastNameElement
                                    .getChildNodes();
                            name = ((Node) textLNList.item(0))
                                    .getNodeValue().trim();
                            stp.NameS = name;
                            stp.Group = group;
                            stp.IdS = id;
                            pasokhgo.add(stp);

                        }

                        if (group.equals("user")) {
                            //----//
                            NodeList firstNameList = firstPersonElement
                                    .getElementsByTagName("id");
                            Element firstNameElement = (Element) firstNameList
                                    .item(0);

                            NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement
                                    .getChildNodes();
                            idTwo = ((Node) textFNList.item(0))
                                    .getNodeValue().trim();
                            //----//
                            NodeList lastNameList = firstPersonElement
                                    .getElementsByTagName("name");
                            Element lastNameElement = (Element) lastNameList
                                    .item(0);

                            NodeList textLNList = lastNameElement
                                    .getChildNodes();
                            nameTwo = ((Node) textLNList.item(0))
                                    .getNodeValue().trim();
                            //----//
                            stp.NameE = nameTwo;
                            stp.Group = group;
                            stp.IdE = idTwo;
                            pasokhgo.add(stp);

                        }
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
        }
```

I had this problem and I can't get data in activity same you I can see just toast but then i fill `listView` in `MyReceiver.class`.